# Craft CMS Manager Craftman - No such file or directory: '//docker-compose.yml'

Tags: php, docker, content-management-system, craftcms

I have used the [craftman](https://github.com/gabrielmoreira/craftman) cms manager for installing craft cms on my computer, and few weeks ago I was able to run the installation of craft locally and that worked fine. But, today I have tried to setup the new project by running this command:

```
craftman --port=8080 install
```

But, I got an error:

> mkdir: //.craftman/config.d: Permission denied mkdir:
>   //.craftman/config.d: Permission denied
>   //.craftman/config.d/docker-ports.conf: No such file or directory

And then on checking the Craft CMS docker containers status by running `craftman status` I got an error:

> No such file or directory: '//docker-compose.yml'